# Inserting GPS coordinates in QGIS

Tags: qgis, gps, coordinates, format

I have a problem with creating - inserting GPS coordinates into QGIS. I have my coordinates in this format: N 45.66209; E 013.99382 and I want to insert them. I am using the function **Numerical Digitize**.

The problem is that when I put them into the function, the location that I get is wrong.
I think the problem is in the format of the coordinates, because when I used the function **Location (X,Y)** I obtained coordinates in this format: 421949.975,58031.353.

How can I transform into this format my coordinates? How is this format called?

Comment: Your coordinates are in degrees, while the other coordinate pair is in meters or feet. You have to add your coordinates in a layer with a CRS that uses degrees, like EPSG:4326. Note that coordinates are expected in Easting-Northing order.

Comment: Thank you, It resolved my problem. Also do you know any program or site, that directly transforms my coordinates from degrees to meters?

Comment: QGIS is able to do the conversion, or the commandline utility cs2cs.